# FIPS 201 Compliant Keyboard with Fingerprint and Smart Card Reader?

Tags: keyboard, fingerprint, smartcard

Anyone know of a keyboard that has **both** a fingerprint and smart card reader and is FIPS 201 compliant?

**Edit**: I'm looking for a product that is currently on the market and certified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Athena Smartcard Solutions do have a combo keyboard. It will be FIPS certified in Q4.
You are welcome to call us at +1 408 914 2808 or write to sales@athena-scs.com
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the FIPS 201 compliance, but [Cherry](http://www.cherrycorp.com/) has keyboards with a fingerprint reader and a smartcard reader, like the [G83-14201](http://www.cherrycorp.com/english/keyboards/Security/Biometric_Keyboards/14201.htm) and the [G83-14401](http://www.cherrycorp.com/english/keyboards/Security/Biometric_Keyboards/14401.htm)

**Edit**: apparently, according to [this press release](http://www.earlybird.de/en/press/portfolio/531/), the sensor TouchChip TSC1 is FIPS 201 compliant. That's the sensor used in the [G83-14401](http://www.cherrycorp.com/english/keyboards/Security/Biometric_Keyboards/14401.htm)

> UPEK’s TouchChip TCS1 fingerprint
>   sensor is the first and only silicon
>   fingerprint sensor to be approved by
>   the FBI and GSA for FIPS 201
>   applications

Cherry G83-14401 specs:

> USB keyboard with fingerprint sensor
>   and PC/SC smart card reader
>
> Capacitive fingerprint sensor TCS1CD from UPEK (ST-Micro) with
>   TouchChip® technology 256x360 pixel

Comment: I've already spoken to Cherry and they don't have FIP's compliant keyboards that have both the smart card reader and the fingerprint reader. Their only FIPS compliant keyboards have only the smart card reader.